# Deploying Mkdocs to Azure web apps

Tags: python, azure, markdown, hosting, mkdocs

Can't seem to deploy **Mkdocs (material) site** to Azure Web Apps. We built an **Mkdocs site** for our collateral and documentation, I have tried several time to host it using **Azure (web app, static app and DevOps)** but nothing seems to work.

**Prefer not to use Git pages or 3rd party hosting apps**
If anyone has done it please could you share a **step-by-step guide** of how this could be done

Below is what my GitHub repository looks like:
[image: Directory]

Answer (score 1):

You could follow one of the static site generator tutorials available like the one for [hugo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-hugo) for example.

There are two main steps really which would be part of your build pipeline like GitHub Actions or an ADO pipeline

1. Generate the static assets

For MkDocs, this is done by running `mkdocs builds`

2. Deploy to Azure

For this, depending on the what your build solution is, use the appropriate plugin for deploying. For GitHub actions, it would be something like this

```yaml
- name: Build And Deploy
   id: builddeploy
   uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
   with:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
      repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for GitHub integrations (i.e. PR comments)
      action: "upload"
      ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match you app requirements. ######
      # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      output_location: "site" # Built app content directory - optional
      ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```